# Who initialize connection for Firebase token?

Tags: android, firebase, token, firewall

My applicaion needs to work in secure environment and it can connect
only with speficic server. In other words, traffic that goes outside our app
is restricted. Because of that I have some doubts about Firebase notifications
functionality in this application.

I need to get Firebase token in order to send it to our server.
Ofcourse Firebase's server needs to identify client device in some way. I assume
that before receiving new token, some part needs to send data (like device id) to Firebase server in order
to generate that token that will be send back to me. So, the questions is... Who is responsible 
for initializing this process? Under the hood, does the system do the work or my application?

Comment: To answer "Who is responsible for initializing this process?" see here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

For get token from firebase, you just need to do :

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("token", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    token = task.getResult().getToken();


                    Log.w("token", token);

                }
            });
```

You don't need to send anything.
For example, in my app I execute this code in SplashScreen, in this case the token can be directly send with the user login request.